# Pandas DataFrame: How to calculate the difference by first row and last row in group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"column1": [338, 519, 871, 1731, 2693, 2963, 3379, 3789, 3910, 4109, 4307, 4800, 4912, 5111, 5341, 5820, 6003, ...],
         "column2": [NaN, 1, 1, 1, 1, NaN, NaN, 2, 2, NaN, NaN, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NaN, NaN], ...}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
>>>      column1  column2
0        338      NaN
1        519      1.0
2        871      1.0
3       1731      1.0
4       2693      1.0
5       2963      NaN
6       3379      NaN
7       3789      2.0
8       3910      2.0
9       4109      NaN
10      4307      NaN
11      4800      3.0
12      4912      3.0
13      5111      3.0
14      5341      3.0
15      5820      3.0
16      6003      NaN
17      ....      ....
```

The integers in `column2` denote "groups" in `column1`, e.g. rows 1-4 is group "1", rows 7-8 is group "2", rows 11-15 is group "3", etc.

I would like to calculate the difference between the first row and last row in each group. The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
df
>>>      column1  column2  column3
0        338      NaN      NaN
1        519      1.0      2174
2        871      1.0      2174
3       1731      1.0      2174
4       2693      1.0      2174
5       2963      NaN      NaN
6       3379      NaN      NaN
7       3789      2.0      121
8       3910      2.0      121
9       4109      NaN      NaN
10      4307      NaN      NaN
11      4800      3.0      1020
12      4912      3.0      1020
13      5111      3.0      1020
14      5341      3.0      1020
15      5820      3.0      1020
16      6003      NaN      NaN
17      ....      ....     ...
```

because:

```
2693-519 = 2174
3910-3789 = 121
5820-4800 = 1020
```

What is the "pandas way" to calculate `column3`? Somehow, one must iterate through `column3`, looking for consecutive groups of values such that `df.column2 != "NaN"`.

EDIT: I realized my example may lead readers to assume the values in `column1` are only increasing. Actually, there are intervals, column `intervals`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
>>>    interval      column1  column2
0      interval1     338      NaN
1      interval1     519      1.0
2      interval1     871      1.0
3      interval1     1731      1.0
4      interval1     2693      1.0
5      interval1     2963      NaN
6      interval1     3379      NaN
7      interval1     3789      2.0
8      interval1     3910      2.0
9      interval1     4109      NaN
10     interval1     4307      NaN
11     interval1     4800      3.0
12     interval1     4912      3.0
13     interval1     5111      3.0
14     interval1     5341      3.0
15     interval1     5820      3.0
16     interval1     6003      NaN
17      ....      ....
18     interval2     12        13
19     interval2     115       13
20     interval2     275       NaN
....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter first and then get difference first and last value in [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['col3'] = df[df.column2.notnull()]
                  .groupby('column2')['column1']
                  .transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])
print (df)
    column1  column2    col3
0       338      NaN     NaN
1       519      1.0  2174.0
2       871      1.0  2174.0
3      1731      1.0  2174.0
4      2693      1.0  2174.0
5      2963      NaN     NaN
6      3379      NaN     NaN
7      3789      2.0   121.0
8      3910      2.0   121.0
9      4109      NaN     NaN
10     4307      NaN     NaN
11     4800      3.0  1020.0
12     4912      3.0  1020.0
13     5111      3.0  1020.0
14     5341      3.0  1020.0
15     5820      3.0  1020.0
16     6003      NaN     NaN
```

EDIT1 by your new data:

```
df['col3'] = df[df.column2.notnull()]
                  .groupby('column2')['column1']
                  .transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])
print (df)
     interval  column1  column2    col3
0   interval1      338      NaN     NaN
1   interval1      519      1.0  2174.0
2   interval1      871      1.0  2174.0
3   interval1     1731      1.0  2174.0
4   interval1     2693      1.0  2174.0
5   interval1     2963      NaN     NaN
6   interval1     3379      NaN     NaN
7   interval1     3789      2.0   121.0
8   interval1     3910      2.0   121.0
9   interval1     4109      NaN     NaN
10  interval1     4307      NaN     NaN
11  interval1     4800      3.0  1020.0
12  interval1     4912      3.0  1020.0
13  interval1     5111      3.0  1020.0
14  interval1     5341      3.0  1020.0
15  interval1     5820      3.0  1020.0
16  interval1     6003      NaN     NaN
18  interval2       12     13.0   103.0
19  interval2      115     13.0   103.0
20  interval2      275      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Will this only work if values in `column1` are increasing? I realized my example may be slightly misleading. See above.

Comment: I think it working too. But there is multiple groups `1` splitted by `NaNs` and need processing this groups separately?

Comment: I think e.g.in `column2` `2.0` is replace by `1.0`

Comment: There is only one unique group `1`, one group `2`, etc. The groups in `interval2` will never be the same as the groups in `interval1`

Comment: Ok, so what is problem? Need last value in group substract with first one? Can you explain more?

Comment: There is an interval, `interval1` with increasing values. Each value is labeled. There are unique groups labeled by integers. `interval1` may have groups 1,2,3,4,5. `interval2` may have groups 6,7,8,9,10,11,12, etc.
The task is the same though: For each group, there is a beginning value (first row) and ending value (last row). I need to know the difference between these two values. Is this clear?

Comment: so need change `.groupby('column2')` to `.groupby(['interval','column2'])` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting some errors. Does `df['col3'] = df[df.column2.notnull()] .groupby(['interval','column2'])['column1'] .transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])` work if the `NaN` values are actually 0?

Comment: If `NaN` are replaced to `0` in `column2`, then need change `df[df.column2.notnull()]` to `df[df.column2 != 0]`

Comment: The solution shows a 'Stata way' outcome. Often one would only want to analyse Column 3 (col3) for each group. Is there a solution which only keeps columns 'interval', column1 and column2?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand. Can you create new question?

Comment: To clarify, col3 contains many repeated observations. If you are only interested in analysing col3 for 'interval' and column2, then the procedure should ideally produce a frame with 'interval', column2, and col3. (Apologies for the typo in the previous comment, it should not have mentioned column1).

Comment: So change variables names dont help like `df['col3'] = df[df.column2.notnull()]
                  .groupby('interval')['column2']
                  .transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])` ? Because `transform` function return new column in original df, so it should work always. But I dont know what are your column(s) for grouping, so maybe need change `.groupby(['interval', 'column2'])['column2']` for grouping by interval with column2. Column after groupby, here column2 (`.groupby('interval')['column2']`) means column for applying lambda function. Need numeric column, because difference.